# Browsing OLAP cubes

Tags: javascript, database, widget, olap, cube

Does anybody know any fine open source cube browser?

Ideally, it would be something built with plain javascript.

Does it even exists?

I'm planing to use it with classic asp agains a SQL database.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can look at [Pentaho Mondrian](http://mondrian.pentaho.org/) (including [JPivot](http://jpivot.sourceforge.net)), or at [Eclipse BIRT](http://eclipse.org/birt)

With these, you get some kind of flexible reporting tools on the most popular databases, and it includes functionality to browse OLAP cubes too.

Comment: Hello I am currently developing a mobile app using react native and firebase. I was told to use some data cube to precompute the queries but I have no idea what is the data cube actually. Is it some sort of multi dimensional array which help you to sort the data? Can I use the suggested links to achieve what I wanted to do?

Answer (score 6):

If you're looking for something lightweight, give [CubesViewer](https://github.com/jjmontesl/cubesviewer) a try:

It's mostly Javascript, backed up by Cubes OLAP server.

*(Disclaimer, I'm the main developer :-))*

Comment: Hey I am currently developing a mobile app using react native and firebase. I was told to precompute the queries using data cube but I have no idea what is it actually or where could I implement it. Do you mind to enlighten me on it?

Answer (score 5):

Check out [js-hypercube](http://code.google.com/p/js-hypercube/) for a javascript-only OLAP library.
The API is pretty simple.  You can deserialize json into a cube object, query for the dimension names, slice the cube, and sum the facts.  From the [documentation](https://github.com/thesmart/js-hypercube/blob/master/README.md):

```
var data = [{"time":1331773202,"facts":{"name":"Super Mario Bros. 2","platform":"Nintendo","staring":"Mario"},"measures":{"rentals":73,"sales":9,"revenue":359.91}}, {"time":1331841602,"facts":{"name":"Metroid","platform":"Nintendo","staring":"Samus"},"measures":{"rentals":43,"sales":6,"revenue":239.94}}]; // ... etc
var cube = ps.Cube.deserialize(data, ['rentals', 'sales', 'revenue'])
console.info('Total Rentals', cube.sum().rentals);
console.info('Revenue at 6pm for Super Nintendo games', '$' + cube.slice({hour: 18, platform: 'Super Nintendo'}).sum(2).revenue);
console.info('Avg rentals per hour for games staring Mario', cube.slice({staring: 'Mario'}).avg(24, 2).rentals + ' units');
```

Here's an example I built using it along with backbone.js: http://jsbin.com/rejekij/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Hey I tried to run the jsbin example but there is nothing shown at the output. Is it still available for now?

Comment: @DeniseTan, I've fixed the jsbin

Comment: Thanks so much! But allow me to ask for a few questions as I am trying to understand what is the data cube actually. From the library, is the results precomputed or compute on the fly? Also, where did you get all the data from? Let's say I am fetching json from Firebase, is it still doable? Then, let's say I have raw json now, how do I actually form a cube?

Answer (score 2):

Also take a look at PAT, which is pentaho's replacement for JPivot.
(Well actually being devloped by the community - not pentaho themselves!)

JPivot is a bit clunky although does the job.  PAT is very new, so can't vouch for it's stability and features!

http://code.google.com/p/pentahoanalysistool/

Comment: hey, nice tip...
is there any online demo???

Comment: demo.pentaho.com/pentaho has a demo of JPivot, but not yet PAT.

Comment: PAT has been renamed Saiku. Its homepage: http://www.analytical-labs.com/. Demo: http://demo.analytical-labs.com/

Answer (score 1):

Adobe Flex includes a control you may be able use. You can use javascript as the language (Flex supports Actionscript natively, and javascript is a subset of Actionscrpt, and can be used as well.)

Here is a web page about the [OLAPDataGrid](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=olapdatagrid_2.html) control.

And here is [another link](http://labs.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/Flex_3:Feature_Introductions:OLAP_API_and_OLAP_Data_Grid).

Flex apps can be hosted in browsers with Flash installed.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at pivot table component at flexmonster.com. It speak to olap cubes via xmla and unlike olapdatagrid does't need additional data preparation.

Answer (score 1):

[WebPivotTable](http://webpivottable.com) is a pure javascript pivot table and pivot chart component which can be used to pivot csv file and all kinds of OLAP cubes, like Mondrian, SSAS, iccube. Here is [demo](http://webpivottable.com/demo) and [documents](http://webpivottable.com/documents).

Comment: Very impressive, it's not open source, but it's free for public sites...

Answer (score 0):

if you can, find the sql server 2000 Resource Kit, inside there is a project that is a javascript cube browser.  i am not sure of the licensing of this, but it is located at TOOLSANDSAMPLES\ANALYSISSERVICESTHINWEBCLIENT inside the Resource Kit.  This resource kit should be available in msdn subscription downloads.

Answer (score 0):

[Ranet Olap component library](https://galaktikasoft.com/ranet-olap/) has open version. Although it doesn't meet your requirement completely (require Silverlight), you should check it out.

Comment: That link is dead.